# How to serialize an instance of a custom class so that all applications with an identical class can read it?

Tags: c#, serialization

I tried using `BinaryFormatter` and a class with one public field (a string) and yet, an identical class in another application couldn't deserialize it.

If possible, I'd like the class to contain a field of its own type (recursive) but if not - `string`s, `int`s, and `byte` arrays are the most important.

Comment: Create a class library and use it in both applications.

Comment: What type of communication are you trying to do between the applications?  Are you only trying to send the properties over?

Comment: @iMortalitySX That's mainly it. But I want someone to be able to write his own application which will then use these files.

Comment: I would go for XML or JSON in that case.

Comment: @Adam Thanks. But isn't XML for text only? (Please excuse the simple question. I don't have experience with it, and Google hasn't uncovered anything clear.)

Comment: @Adam Never mind. I found some stuff about it. Reading now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't share a class library between applications, you can create a mirroring class in the client (consumer) application and map all its properties to the properties of the "initial" class + some auxillary info. This will be your proxy class. Then, you should take control over the deserialization process. For instance, use xml to hold data. You can encrypt the contents of the file and share the public key between applications if security is critical.

Comment: "map all its properties..." - What do you mean?

Comment: "use xml to hold data" - isn't xml text only?

Comment: i mean: create a "proxy" class the will reflect the same properties as the serialized class. Then, during deserialization, instantiate objects of the proxy class and fill them with values by hand,

Comment: But how will I deserialize the original in order to get those values? Am I missing something here?

Comment: As i said, you should take control over the serialization and deserialization processes. The easiest way is to store your data in xml (if you're not operating complex & nested data-structures). In fact, xml can be used to transfer data of arbitrary complexity. The SOAP messaging protocol is based on xml. Another pros of using xml to store data is platform & language independence. U can save data in java application and then consume it by .net app.

Answer (score 1):

The BinaryFormatter will include the full type name (assembly and namespace included) in the output.  You need to use a custom SerializationBinder to read it:

```
public class CustomBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    static string assemblyToUse = typeof (MyObject).Assembly.FullName;
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (typeName.EndsWith("MyType"))
            return typeof(MyTypeInThisAssembly);
        return base.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
    }
}


var formatter = new BinaryFormatter{Binder = new CustomBinder()};
var obj = formatter.Deserialize(...)
```

This has the downside of having to include the code for the CustomFormatter in every assembly tho, which I'm guessing is not what you want.  This probably leaves you with having to use a custom format output (like [JSON](http://json.codeplex.com/) or [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) )